# Autoreload does not work in Celery

Tags: python, django, celery

I am using Celery with Django. 
It works fine if I start it with:

```
celery -A panel worker -l debug
```

But when I enable `autoreload` feature Celery does not take tasks from a queue.

I tried to force it to use ionotify (pyionify is installed):

```
env CELERYD_FSNOTIFY=inotify celery -A panel worker -l debug --autoreload
```

But no success. The last line in the debug output is:

```
[2015-04-25 23:10:19,830: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Hub.register
```

What can be wrong?

Comment: try supervisor. it becomes bit easier to auto reload multiple workers

Answer (score 1):

I definitely remeber posting a bug on github and trying to fix this. You can see all here: https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/2249

But now I can't help with it.

PS: I don't trust autoreloading in Python, especially in big projects. Often can cause hard to debug errors.